# Update If Tables Match Else Set the rest to misc content

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables. Table A and Table B . Table A grows over time and Table B has a fixed number of rows. Table A has data that needs to be transferred to tableB only when either two columns in Table A match tableB's RowID and when the status in tableA is less than 9.

I want to update tableB if it matches and if it doesnt, I want the other values in the rest of tableB to be set to 'dummy' data.

I am able to update where they do match, but I am having difficulties in setting the values where they do not match.

How do I upon updating tableB when they match, set the rest of tableB's columns to 'dummy' data?

Any help is most appreicated.

[image]
[image]

```
 IF EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT b.* 
               FROM   tableB b 
                      INNER JOIN tableA a 
                              ON b.workcell = a.enclosureloc 
                                  OR b.workcell = a.panelloc 
               WHERE  ( b.workcell = a.enclosureloc 
                         OR b.workcell = a.panelloc ) 
                      AND a.status < 9) 
      UPDATE b 
      SET    b.job = a.job, 
             b.date = a.date, 
             b.enclosureloc = a.enclosureloc, 
             b.panelloc = a.panelloc
      FROM   tablea b 
             INNER JOIN tableA a 
                     ON b.workcell = a.enclosureloc 
                         OR b.workcell = a.panelloc 
      WHERE  a.status < 9 
    ELSE --I am Stuck HERE...Maybe there is an easier way in General???
      UPDATE b 
      SET    b.job = '123', 
             b.date = '00-00', 
             b.enclosureloc = 99, 
             b.panelloc = 99 
      FROM   tablea b
```

Comment: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/the-merge-statement-in-sql-server-2008/ Have you tried MERGE query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change to `LEFT JOIN`, and use `COALESCE(b.value,'junk value')`:

```
  UPDATE a 
  SET    a.job = COALESCE(b.job,'123'), 
         a.date = COALESCE(b.date,'00-00'), 
         a.enclosureloc = COALESCE(b.enclosureloc,99),
         a.panelloc = COALESCE(b.panelloc,99)
  FROM   tablea a 
         LEFT JOIN tableB b 
                 ON (a.workcell = b.enclosureloc OR a.workcell = b.panelloc) 
                  AND b.status < 9
```

Don't think you need any `IF..ELSE` at all with the above.

Edit:  Also requires moving the `WHERE` criteria to the `JOIN` since it would negate the `LEFT JOIN`.